# Library won't compile - Compiling transformation Metadata file not found

Tags: c#, nuget

I get this error when trying to compile my library.

```
Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'C:\Users\Me\Project\Project\bin\Debug\DocoptNet.dll' could not be found    Solution 'Project' ‎(1 project) C:\Users\Me\Project\Project\T4DocoptNet.tt
```

I recently removed the Docopt package from my solution and now it won't compile at all. How do I fix this?

Obviously the file doesn't exist because nuget removed it, and I can't find any references to Docopt in my project.

Cleaning the project doesn't do anything either, it still complains about this .tt file when I try a rebuild.

Comment: It doesn't uninstall properly, you must remove T4DocoptNet.tt from the project yourself.  Right-click, Delete.

Comment: I already have, it's not in the project, or in the solution. I've verified this by looking in the folder with Windows Explorer.